# Async timeout - error handling logic

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand the difference in the code behaviour between the two cases:

1. if (t != **await** Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(500)))
2. if (t != Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(150))**.Result**)

I understand the second one is going to be slower as we wait for one or the other immediately.

The whole function:

```
public async Task<string> TestAsyncTimeout()
        {
            var test =WebRequest.Create("https://10.11.12.13");
            var t = test.GetResponseAsync();

            //if (t != await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(500)))
            if (t != Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(150)).Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out");
                test.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Request aborted");
                throw new Exception("Timed out");
            }

            return (await t).ContentLength.ToString();
        }
```

This function calls non existing IP and always times out.

Why is case 2) throwing unobserved Unobserved exception from TaskScheduler: 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

While case 1 only throws 'Timed out' exception but never the above ?

I'm awaiting the task outside the function in:
try { task.Wait() } catch { log exception }

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

The difference appears to be caused by how the background tasks are handled. 
When I started forcing GC to run after both requests finished the Unobserved exception has been thrown in both cases.